# use variable as the result dataset

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to PostgreSql, used to work with SQL Server.
I'm having trouble understanding one scenario, quite simple from Sql Server perspective.
I need to have as the query result (e.g. dataset) the value of a variable.

I Sql Server i'd have something like this:

```
  Declare @cnt int
  Delete from MyTable
  set @cnt = @@ROWCOUNT
  select @cnt as FinalResult
```

The expected result was to use the value of the variable (e.g. @cnt as my resultset).
I tried the same  in PostgreSql, using the follwoing code:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
     affected_rows integer;
BEGIN
  delete from mySchema.MyTable;
   GET DIAGNOSTICS affected_rows := ROW_COUNT;
    raise notice  'affected records: %', affected_rows; 
    select affected_rows as result;
END $$;
```

Obviously it throws me an error.
Could you please advise on how to approach it?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the error you get is "query has no destination for result data"  which is caused by the `select affected_rows as result;` line. In Postgres' PL/pgSQL (and essentially every other procedural language in relational databases - except for T-SQL), the result of a query needs to be stored somewhere.

A `do` block is like a temporary function that does not return anything, so the only way to give feedback from there, is to use `raise notice` to print the number of deleted rows. You can't have a SELECT statement returning something from a DO block.

But you don't need PL/pgSQL for that to begin with:

```
with deleted as (
  delete from table
  returning *
)
select count(*) as final_result
from deleted;
```

Comment: very nice, thanks. But still, if my usecase should be other, is there even the concept of exposing the value of a variable as final result ?

Comment: thanks alot for the detailed info. It makes alot of sense now.